# jQuery html form not identifying the live elements

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a html form, that i need to submit to server, but before i need to validate the form, i have few dynamic drop downs that needs to be captured as well on form submit event, but all other fields gets validated and loop don't identify the live drop downs.

I have already tried capturing the live fields in other loop, but in vain.

I have never faced this issue before, i have captured the even like

```
jQuery(document).on( "submit", "#adminForm", function(){} );
```

Is this responsible for this issue?

Comment: If you can put your code here, that would be great!

Comment: Can you make it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: jQuery(document).on('submit','#adminForm',function(event){
===========================================================
Here below i do the loop, all the controls have .form-control class, those dynamically generated dropdowns as well have this class, but this loop does not validate them
===========================================================
jQuery('.form-control').each(function(){

Comment: how to use linebrakes in the comment? :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qnze0oz8/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#adminForm").submit(function (event) {
    jQuery("input[type='text'], select, textarea").each(function (i) {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == "") {
            alert("This field is required: " + $(this).attr("name"));
        }
    });
});
```

This might give you some guidance.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wmjv0re/1/

Comment: Is your dropdown dynamically created? no

Comment: As I said, guidance. You have posted no code. The above should work in most circumstances. You say dynamic, are they populated server-side or client-side, are you getting any errors in code? There isn't enough information in your question to give you an accurate answer.

Comment: Use firebug, and check you dynamically created drop downs actually have the `.form-control` class.

Comment: Yes i have already checked the class names being appearing in the firebug, they are populated server-side. there are not errors in the console as well.

Comment: i wanna paste the code here, but how to use line brakes in the comment?

Answer (score 0):

Use it with jquery's live() as:

```
jQuery("#adminForm").on( "submit", function(){} );
```

Comment: That depends on the jquery version you are using. Try with on() in the same manner. And, can you please post your complete snippet where you are facing the problem. It would be great..!!